# After JMP command, the program doesn't return to the place it was called

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm trying to write a simple graphics engine for DOSBOX and it's going fairly well, I've been using some code from https://github.com/adamsmasher/sokobanDOS/
My problem is that after I call the JMP command to go to drawpixel the program doesn't return to main, at least I don't think it does. After the drawpixel it's supposed to return to text which I've tested on it's own and it works.
I'm new to assembly so I don't really know what I'm doing.

```
jmp initgraph

main:
    MOV CX, 320
    JMP drawpixel
    JMP returntext
    JMP main

initgraph:
    MOV AX, 13h
    INT 10h
    MOV CX, 0
    JMP main

returntext:
    MOV AX, 0x03
    INT 0x10
    RET

drawpixel:
    MOV AX, 0A000h
    MOV ES, AX
    MOV AX, CX
    MOV DI, AX
    MOV DL, 0xE
    MOV [ES:DI], DL
```

It's supposed to just really quickly display a pixel and return to text mode but instead it sort of freezes and doesn't return to text.

Comment: Why are you using JMP rather than CALL to reach returntext and drawpixel? (drawpixel should also end with a `ret`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did that and it just started a blinking cursor and is there a reason I should use call over jmp. I found a fix for the first thing the return text should be a JMP not call.

Comment: Your cursor is blinking because `jmp main` puts your program in an infinite loop and you never exit back to DOS.

Comment: @MichaelPetch is it not because when I changed JMP returntext to CALL returntext it wouldn't exit because it's calling not jumping?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using `JMP` rather than `CALL`.

When you use `JMP` (or any of its conditional variations) you are instructing the CPU to replace the current instruction pointer with the immediate or calculated value encoded with the operand.  No provision is made to keep track of where you were.

When you use the `CALL` operation, the address of the following opcode is pushed onto the stack, `SP` is decremented by the appropriate stack width, and the immediate/calculated value in the call is placed into the instruction pointer.  This allows you to use the `RET` instruction to return to the previous execution location.

Example code that uses `CALL`, enters graphics mode, plots a pixel, waits for a key, returns to text mode and then exits back to DOS could look like:

```
org 100h

main:
    CALL initgraph
    MOV CX, 320
    CALL drawpixel
    CALL waitforkey
    CALL returntext

    MOV AX, 4C00h               ; Exit to DOS returning exit code 00h
    INT 21h

waitforkey:
    MOV AH, 0                   ; Int 16h/AH=0 get key BIOS call
    INT 16h
    RET

initgraph:
    MOV AX, 13h
    INT 10h
    MOV CX, 0
    RET

returntext:
    MOV AX, 0x03
    INT 0x10
    RET

drawpixel:
    MOV AX, 0A000h
    MOV ES, AX
    MOV AX, CX
    MOV DI, AX
    MOV DL, 0xE
    MOV [ES:DI], DL
    RET
```